# Deserializing custom types

Tags: yamldotnet

The below xaml loosely describes a number of steps that can be re-arranged into many different configurations, and nested levels.

```
---
sequence:
  - manual:
    desc: unpack baloons
  - electric:
    desc: inflate each balloon
  - parallel:
    - manual:
      desc: seal a balloon
    - manual:
      desc: sign a balloon
    - sequence:
      - manual:
        desc: step 1
      - manual:
        desc: step 2
```

There are a number of *resolvers and *converters, however a good advice on which one to use when would be very helpful. How to register custom type factories and in what places?